# PHP - Authentication without password (OAuth neither)

Tags: php, apache, authentication, oauth, jwt

I want to enter from my web to another, which is located in another server and it has a login.

Until now, I am accessing to this web by apache reverse proxy and a harcorded credentials in my code, but it is not secure.

My idea is make it with some type of authentication token and I found JWT's, but I have absolutely forbidden to use OAuth in the project.
So, anyone could recommend me any solution without OAuth technology?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe your specific problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JWT with a shared secret key in the signature in stead of OAuth.